# Помогите заполнить таблицу QTableWidget из файла .csv

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, csv, qtablewidget

Помогите заполнить таблицу `QTableWidget` из файла **`.csv`**. Перепробовал много вариантов, не получается.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainUchet_KLS(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainUchet_KLS):
        MainUchet_KLS.setObjectName("MainUchet_KLS")
        MainUchet_KLS.setEnabled(True)
        MainUchet_KLS.resize(950, 400)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainUchet_KLS.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainUchet_KLS.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 5, 750, 350))
        self.tabWidget.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(5, 5))
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 745, 325))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(5)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tableWidget.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(5, 5))
        self.tableWidget.setToolTip("")
        self.tableWidget.setWhatsThis("")
        self.tableWidget.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.tableWidget.setAutoScrollMargin(15)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(187, 193, 183))
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setKerning(True)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.NoAntialias)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(7, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(8, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(9, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(70)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(10)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(20)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setHighlightSections(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(20)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tableWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 745, 365))
        self.tableWidget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 365))
        self.tableWidget_2.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget_2.setObjectName("tableWidget_2")
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(10)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(7, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(8, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(9, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(6)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setItem(1, 1, item)
        self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(70)
        self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(70)
        self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeader().setHighlightSections(True)
        self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(20)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 143, 271))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_3.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.checkBox_3.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_2, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_4 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_4.setObjectName("checkBox_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_4, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 160, 320))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(175, 205, 235);")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 10, 155, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.widget.raise_()
        self.tabWidget.raise_()
        self.gridLayoutWidget.raise_()
        MainUchet_KLS.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainUchet_KLS.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 950, 21))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.menuCtrl_P = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuCtrl_P.setObjectName("menuCtrl_P")
        self.menu_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menu_2.setObjectName("menu_2")
        MainUchet_KLS.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.actionAlt_F4 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.actionAlt_F4.setObjectName("actionAlt_F4")
        self.action_ODF_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.action_ODF_2.setObjectName("action_ODF_2")
        self.action_Ctrl_P = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.action_Ctrl_P.setObjectName("action_Ctrl_P")
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_8 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.action_8.setObjectName("action_8")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.action_3 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.action_3.setObjectName("action_3")

        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_8)
        self.menu.addAction(self.actionAlt_F4)
        self.menuCtrl_P.addAction(self.action_ODF_2)
        self.menuCtrl_P.addAction(self.action_Ctrl_P)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action_2)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action_3)
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuCtrl_P.menuAction())
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menu_2.menuAction())


        self.retranslateUi(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.actionAlt_F4.triggered.connect(MainUchet_KLS.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainUchet_KLS)
        MainUchet_KLS.setTabOrder(self.tabWidget, self.tableWidget)
        MainUchet_KLS.setTabOrder(self.tableWidget, self.tableWidget_2)
        MainUchet_KLS.setTabOrder(self.tableWidget_2, self.checkBox_4)
        MainUchet_KLS.setTabOrder(self.checkBox_4, self.checkBox_2)
        MainUchet_KLS.setTabOrder(self.checkBox_2, self.checkBox_3)
        MainUchet_KLS.setTabOrder(self.checkBox_3, self.checkBox)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainUchet_KLS):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainUchet_KLS.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Учет"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "№"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Название"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Номер"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Дата\n"
"ввода"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Сеть"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Марка\n"
"продукта"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "По\n"
"грунту, км"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(7)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "По ККС,\n"
"км"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(8)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "По\n"
"стене, км"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(9)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Трасса, км"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainUchet_KLS", "1 таблица"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "№"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Название"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "количество\n"
"КИП"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Информ.\n"
"знаков, шт"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Замерных\n"
"столбиков, шт"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "ККС, шт"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Количество\n"
"мест, шт"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(7)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Длина\n"
"просеки, км"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(8)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Проверка\n"
"глубины, шт"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(9)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "длина,км"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget_2.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget_2.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.tableWidget_2.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainUchet_KLS", "2 таблица"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "номеру"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "названию"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "году "))
        self.checkBox_4.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "принадлежности "))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Сортировка"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Поиск"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Обновить"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Поиск или Сортировка"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Администрирование"))
        self.menuCtrl_P.setTitle(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Отчет"))
        self.menu_2.setTitle(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Справка"))
        self.actionAlt_F4.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Alt +F4"))
        self.action_ODF_2.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "В ODF"))
        self.action_Ctrl_P.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Печать Ctrl+P"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Пользователь "))
        self.action_8.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Линия"))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Инструкция пользователя"))
        self.action_3.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "О программе"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainUchet_KLS = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainUchet_KLS()
    ui.setupUi(MainUchet_KLS)
    MainUchet_KLS.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Где же хоть один вариант из этого множества?

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, в следующий раз, показывайте что вы пробовали сделать для решения вашего вопроса.

**main.py**

```
import csv                                                             # +++
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainUchet_KLS(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainUchet_KLS):
        MainUchet_KLS.setObjectName("MainUchet_KLS")
        MainUchet_KLS.setEnabled(True)
        MainUchet_KLS.resize(950, 400)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainUchet_KLS.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainUchet_KLS.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 5, 750, 350))
        self.tabWidget.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(5, 5))
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 745, 325))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(5)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tableWidget.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(5, 5))
        self.tableWidget.setToolTip("")
        self.tableWidget.setWhatsThis("")
        self.tableWidget.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.tableWidget.setAutoScrollMargin(15)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(187, 193, 183))
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setKerning(True)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.NoAntialias)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(7, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(8, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(9, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(70)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(10)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(20)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setHighlightSections(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(20)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tableWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 745, 365))
        self.tableWidget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 365))
        self.tableWidget_2.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget_2.setObjectName("tableWidget_2")
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(10)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(7, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(8, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(9, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(6)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget_2.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setItem(1, 1, item)
        self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(70)
        self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(70)
        self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeader().setHighlightSections(True)
        self.tableWidget_2.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(20)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 143, 271))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_3.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.checkBox_3.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_2, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox_4 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_4.setObjectName("checkBox_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox_4, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 160, 320))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(175, 205, 235);")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 10, 155, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.widget.raise_()
        self.tabWidget.raise_()
        self.gridLayoutWidget.raise_()
        MainUchet_KLS.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainUchet_KLS.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 950, 21))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.menuCtrl_P = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuCtrl_P.setObjectName("menuCtrl_P")
        self.menu_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menu_2.setObjectName("menu_2")
        MainUchet_KLS.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.actionAlt_F4 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.actionAlt_F4.setObjectName("actionAlt_F4")
        self.action_ODF_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.action_ODF_2.setObjectName("action_ODF_2")
        self.action_Ctrl_P = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.action_Ctrl_P.setObjectName("action_Ctrl_P")
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_8 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.action_8.setObjectName("action_8")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.action_3 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.action_3.setObjectName("action_3")

        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_8)
        
        self.menu.addAction(self.actionAlt_F4)
        
        
        self.menuCtrl_P.addAction(self.action_ODF_2)
        self.menuCtrl_P.addAction(self.action_Ctrl_P)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action_2)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action_3)
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuCtrl_P.menuAction())
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menu_2.menuAction())


        self.retranslateUi(MainUchet_KLS)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.actionAlt_F4.triggered.connect(MainUchet_KLS.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainUchet_KLS)
        MainUchet_KLS.setTabOrder(self.tabWidget, self.tableWidget)
        MainUchet_KLS.setTabOrder(self.tableWidget, self.tableWidget_2)
        MainUchet_KLS.setTabOrder(self.tableWidget_2, self.checkBox_4)
        MainUchet_KLS.setTabOrder(self.checkBox_4, self.checkBox_2)
        MainUchet_KLS.setTabOrder(self.checkBox_2, self.checkBox_3)
        MainUchet_KLS.setTabOrder(self.checkBox_3, self.checkBox)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainUchet_KLS):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainUchet_KLS.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Учет"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "№"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Название"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Номер"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Дата\n"
"ввода"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Сеть"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Марка\n"
"продукта"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "По\n"
"грунту, км"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(7)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "По ККС,\n"
"км"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(8)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "По\n"
"стене, км"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(9)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Трасса, км"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainUchet_KLS", "1 таблица"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "№"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Название"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "количество\n"
"КИП"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Информ.\n"
"знаков, шт"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Замерных\n"
"столбиков, шт"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "ККС, шт"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Количество\n"
"мест, шт"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(7)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Длина\n"
"просеки, км"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(8)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Проверка\n"
"глубины, шт"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(9)
        item.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "длина,км"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget_2.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget_2.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.tableWidget_2.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainUchet_KLS", "2 таблица"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "номеру"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "названию"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "году "))
        self.checkBox_4.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "принадлежности "))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Сортировка"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Поиск"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Обновить"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Поиск или Сортировка"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Администрирование"))
        self.menuCtrl_P.setTitle(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Отчет"))
        self.menu_2.setTitle(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Справка"))
        self.actionAlt_F4.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Alt +F4"))
        self.action_ODF_2.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "В ODF"))
        self.action_Ctrl_P.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Печать Ctrl+P"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Пользователь "))
        self.action_8.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Линия"))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "Инструкция пользователя"))
        self.action_3.setText(_translate("MainUchet_KLS", "О программе"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainUchet_KLS):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.new_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Заполнить таблицу', self)
        self.menu.insertAction(self.actionAlt_F4, self.new_action)       
        self.menu.triggered.connect(self.selected)
                 
    def selected(self, q):
        #print('\n{} <- selected -> {}'.format(q.text(), q))
        if q.text() == 'Заполнить таблицу':
            path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
                self, 'Open CSV', '.', 'CSV(*.csv)') 
            if not path:
                return
            if self.tabWidget.currentIndex() == 0:
                with open(path, newline='') as csv_file:
                    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
                    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)
                    my_file = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
                    for row_data in my_file:
                        row = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
                        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
                        if len(row_data) > 10:
                            self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(row_data))
                            
                        for column, stuff in enumerate(row_data):
                            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(stuff)
                            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, item)
            elif self.tabWidget.currentIndex() == 1:
                with open(path, newline='') as csv_file:
                    self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(0)
                    self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(10)
                    my_file = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
                    for row_data in my_file:
                        row = self.tableWidget_2.rowCount()
                        self.tableWidget_2.insertRow(row)
                        if len(row_data) > 10:
                            self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(len(row_data))
                            
                        for column, stuff in enumerate(row_data):
                            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(stuff)
                            self.tableWidget_2.setItem(row, column, item)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1285948.csv**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28
31,32,33,34
41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо. я так бы и сделал но кроме заполнения из поиска ничего не получалось.

Comment: @Serg_77 Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Serg_77 я ответил на ваш вопрос?

Comment: да на этот в полном объеме.